# Changing language default in chrome os

Tags: google-chrome-os

I am curious if the default language during setup can be chosen by the user, or can it be changed in any other manner? I ask because I am in a Latin country and need to use English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Google Chromebook support](https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/1059490?hl=en):

> You can adjust the language used for your screens and menus, spell-check, and for viewing webpages.
>   If you haven’t already, sign in to your Chromebook.
>   Click the status area in the lower-right corner, where your account picture appears.
>   Select Settings.
>   Click Show advanced settings at the bottom of the page.
>   In the “Language” section, click Customize languages and input.
>   You can then adjust the following settings:

Comment: Ok, thank you. I have not purchased one yet, though if i do, I want to know the language can be changed.